# Cannot load IMG without specifying extension

Tags: .htaccess, image, mime, mime-type

I just moved to a new server. All my site is including images without extensions. () but the new server doesn't seem to recognize this files unless I add each file's extension which I don't know so I need it to work without the extension.

Example: http://lujanventas.com/test.php

What can be the reason for the images not showing? And what can I do to make them work?

```
% curl http://lujanventas.com/test.php
<html>
<body>
No extension:</br>
<img class="itemImage" src="/uploads/thumbs/619-0"></br>
With extension:</br>
<img class="itemImage" src="/uploads/thumbs/619-0.jpg"></br>
</body>
</html>

% curl -I http://lujanventas.com/uploads/thumbs/619-0
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.lujanventas.com/404.php

% curl -I http://lujanventas.com/uploads/thumbs/619-0.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The service provider is MediaTemple and the server uses Apache

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm running Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to enable MultiViews [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#negotiation), which makes Apache select an appropriate representation of a resource. The following directive in `.htaccess` or an appropriate `<Directory>`, `<Location>` or `<Files>` section should do that.

```
Options MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache is using file extension to determine file type and associate corresponding mime-type to Content-Type header.

You can also use `SetHandler image/jpeg` in .htaccess to force all file in this directory to be represented as image.

Comment: I don't understand, if Apache was determining the correct file type correctly wouldn't it show the images? That seems like a good solution. I created an .htaccess file on the /thumbs directory with only `SetHandler image/jpeg` as content but images are still not displayed. Was that what I was supposed to do?

Comment: Your server answers to `http://lujanventas.com/uploads/thumbs/619-0` request with 302 redirect to http://www.lujanventas.com/404.php.
The problem is not with file extension.